# Unable to install php 7 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, php7

Commands I have tried :

```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

Getting error as

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Unable to locate package php7.2
 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2'
```

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 went EOL in April 2019. Due to which most repository information for trusty are now unavailable including ondrej's. Consider upgrading to a supported version.

Answer (score 2):

Ondrej's PPA is not working with unsupported Ubuntu versions (below 16.04 at this time).
Take a look [here](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+packages?field.name_filter=php7.0&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=). Ubuntu 14.04 reached its end of unpaid support on April 30, 2019 as per the [Ubuntu Wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: I really don't get the downvoting trend on StackExchange. Is there anything wrong with my answer? Just leave a comment...

Comment: I suspect the tone of the second sentence inspired the downvote. I would write "Ubuntu 14.04 reached its end of unpaid support on April 30, 2019 as per https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases"